# Notify other activities of the same application to finish it self from one activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application which have 5 activities and any of the activity can access other 4.  In one of the activities i have a `Finish` button that should put my application on background thread. I want to notify my other activities to call `finish()`, and for that i have two ideas in mind. One is by using `intent` but other is using `interface` but i'm little confused to decide on which way should i go?

Are there any other way to notify all activities on same application from an event of one activity?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but is it not OK if you use thread synchronization???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got finally what i wanted, I need to send the whole application in background and stop all services used.. Stopping services was a lot easier than I had thought at the time when I asked the question.

And sending application in background is even easier because there is an sdk supported method to send an application to background

```
ActivityClass.moveTaskToBack(true);
```

If you are in activity class you can directly call the method.

Here is the documentation of the method

> If false then this only works if the
>   activity is the root of a task; if
>   true it will work for any activity in
>   a task.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just call `((Activity) context).finish();` where `context` is the context of the activity you want to call `finish()` on.

Comment: Sorry to say that i'm not clear with your answer, suppose my ActivityClass is `SettingsActivity.java` and i want this code to be clicked on `OnClickView` of a button. So i will get `Context context = view.getContext`. is it possible to Cast in `HomeActivity.java` which i want to finish?? It may sound silly but this doubt stops me to implement it.

Comment: @MobileDev123: I think you got me wrong. You have to pass/get the context of the activity you want to stop and then you are calling finish on that context by casting the context to Activity. So what I mean is that you con't cast to any activity in particular but you cast to the base class `Activity` to get access to the `finish()` method.

Comment: hmm got you. So its better if i call `finish()` on the activity itself before i call `startActivity()` of `startActivityForResult()` . Or is there any similar attribute to add in menifest something like `singleTop` ? (I'm not sure about the word)

Comment: @MobileDev123: I'm sure there is an easier and more elegant way but I can't recall which one it was.

Answer (score 0):

in Finish onclick function call finish() of all the other  Activities
ie

(activities which u wanna close).**finish()**

Hope this will help